# How is the power of a component fixed?

Tags: power

How can we say that a bulb is a 100 watt bulb or a heater is a 1000 watt heater when when according to the relations

P=VI, V^2/R and I^2*R

the power depends upon the current and voltage applied to the component while its resistance is fixed?

What if I apply a much lower voltage to a 100 watt bulb? The resistance of the bulb is the same and much less current flows through it. Won't that make the power dissipation much less because of less current through and voltage across it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The power of electrical loads is always at a specified voltage. Examples are 230 V (Europe), 120 V (North America), 12 V (automobile).

> What if I apply a much lesser voltage to a 100 watt bulb?

The power demand will reduce and so will the light output.

> The resistance of the bulb is same and much less current flows through it.

An incandescent light bulb is a poor example as the resistance varies with filament temperature. The cold (switch-on) current can be up to ten times that of the steady state current. That's why they often "pop" on switch-on.

> Won't that make the power dissipation much less because of less current through and voltage across it?

Yes.

Comment: My cell phone charger is another poor example, since it delivers the same fixed amount of power to the phone over a wide range of supply voltages. If you turn up the voltage that you're feeding to my charger, then the current goes _down._

Answer (score 10):

The specified power is only true for the rated voltage. Your 100 W incandescent bulb will also be marked “220-240 V” or “120 V”. Same for a space heater or stove.

If you apply less voltage, it will consume less current. For mains connected appliances, this isn’t an issue as the voltage is fixed to a narrow range.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers: there is a wide class of appliances that consume more or less constant power, independent of the voltage (within reasonable limits).

E. g. a water pump with an asynchronous motor will run at constant speed (depending on the mains frequency) and at constant pressure (depending on the water levels) and as both the motor efficiency and the impeller efficiency will be more or less constant it will use constant (active) power for a wide range of voltages (e.g 180V to 250V if we talk about 230V grid).

Or a phone charger - if you plug a fairly discharged phone, it will draw e.g. 18W from the charger and the charger will draw like 19W from the grid, no matter if it is 100V, 120V or 240V as you travel around the world.

On the other hand, not all devices are made equal and most electrical appliances will vary in both consumption and performance as you vary the voltage. Sometimes it is even normal to have more than one power rating for the same thing - e.g. it is normal for a water heater to be rated 4kW at 240V and 3kW at 208V

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on which component the power rating is for.

To start, Alternating Current (AC) systems are usually considered fixed for a given region/city/state/country and are specified by their RMS value. 230V, 120V, 220V, 127V are some common values.

Ignoring smaller and transient changes to the component's characteristics, for resistive components like light bulbs and heaters the power is usually specified for a fixed input voltage, and the component will use all that power while on. The calculation for that is usually straightforward and you may usually consider the component as a resistor: if you lower the voltage input, the current draw and power will drop.

For capacitive and inductive loads, such as electric motors, it is more common to spec the peak power draw (for example, when the motor is starting). The same goes for dynamic systems, for which the power draw is variable (i.e. a TV set, which draws full power when on and with full brightness and audio power, but very little while off). This way, an electrician may easily calculate the maximum power of a whole system by adding up the components' powers, which will determine the specs for the wiring and breaker.

If you input more voltage, current or power than the component is spec'ed for, the usual result is that the component fails (either a fuse is blown, or some part is "fried", maybe even resulting in a fire). If you input less voltage than the spec, the result depends on the component's internals: a resistor-like load will draw less power, but an electronic switching PSU may still work, since the internal circuitry will compensate for the lower voltage by drawing more current. For those, the spec is actually a range of voltages which will draw the same total power.

For example, a phone charger may be specified as "INPUT 100-240V 0.5A, OUTPUT 5V 1A", which means that it will supply a 5V output with *up to* 1A if the phone supports it and only while charging, regardless of the input voltage, but only as long as it is between 100V and 240V. After charging, the output voltage will still be 5V, but the phone will draw much less current, usually just a trickle.

In a similar way, a resistor in a PCB may be specified as "1/2 W", which means that you can *usually* operate it for any combination of voltage and current that results in a power value lower than that. But beware that this is just a rule of thumb when using "normal" voltages and currents: the component also does have a *maximum* voltage and current specs, but it's harder to find the datasheet with those limits.